# Script works partially in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

The following code works somewhat in chrome and IE but not in Firefox.

The idea is to force users to check an "Agree" box before advancing by following either one of the possible links available.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function agreeCheck() 
        {

        valid = false;

        var agree = document.getElementById('agree');
            if(isAgree(agree)){
            valid= true;
            }

        return valid;
        } 

        function isAgree(elem)
        {
            if ( elem.checked == false )
                {
            Show_Stuff(agreespan, "true");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
            Show_Stuff(agreespan, "false");
            return true;
            }
        }
        function Show_Stuff(warning,on_off)
        // Function that will swap the display/no display for
        // all content within span tags
        {

        if ((warning.style.display == "none")&&(on_off =="true"))
            {
            warning.style.display = "";
            }
        else
            {
            warning.style.display = "none";
            }


        }
</script>

    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="signed" id="agree">
I agree</input> <span ID="agreespan" style="display: none">
<font color="red">You must agree in order to proceed</font> 
                                    </span> 

 <button type="button" title="Proceedt" class="btn-proceed" onclick="if (agreeCheck()==true){ window.location='myURL'; } else{ return agreeCheck();}"></button>

<input type="image" src="anotherURL" title="myTitle"  onClick="return agreeCheck();"/>
```

Notes:

1. obviously myURL and anotherURL are
   actual valid URLs
2. clicking on the first button when the box is not checked prevents the page from progressing but does not reveal the error message in the span in Chrome and IE.  In Firefox it does nothing regardless of the box status
3. clicking the image link (input type="image") when the box is not checked works well in Chrome and IE and the error message appears.  In Firefox the link is followed regardless of the box's status.
4. I realize that this could be written differently to simplify things.  The problem is that I am implementing this in Magento where I only have access to chunks of code separately so I can't combine the parts of the If Else statement in a separate function.

---

**edit: I changed the if statement (one line before last) to

```
if (agree.checked ==true){ ...
```

this fixed the issue in chrome and IE and now those browsers are behaving properly.  Firefox is still not doing what I want it to do

Comment: Off the top of my head, you may be having trouble with attempting to access your "agreespan" span tag directly by its ID. I don't know if that is cross browser compatible. You should consider using "document.getElemenyById" like you're doing in agreeCheck function when accessing the "agree" checkbox.

Comment: A couple of unrelated syntax problems: You forgot to declare `valid` with a `var` statement, as is it is an implied global.  You don't really even need `valid` in there you could just return `true` inside the if or `false` if it makes it past the if. Instead of passing `"true"` and `"false"` as strings you should just use the `true` and `false` primitives.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in isAgree function. Try the following:

```
function isAgree(elem)
{
        if (!elem.checked == "Checked")
        {
            Show_Stuff(agreespan, "true");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Show_Stuff(agreespan, "false");
            return true;
        }
}
```

Hope it solves the issue. The solution resolves around this "checked" property.

Comment: thanks but this does not work.  in fact it breaks the functionality that did work in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

span_tag.style.display is used for layout purposes not to hide or show the span tag
It doesn't work in your case because the JavaScript is probably breaking.
Try changing everything to use the following code

```
warning.style.visibility = "hidden";
warning.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: "For layout purposes"? Isn't that what we're doing here? `display` and `visibility` are not the same as each other, but they both hide and show elements and for the scenario the OP describes I would say `display` is a better fit so that there isn't an empty space left when the `span` is not shown.

Comment: @nnnnnnnn you have a gross misunderstanding of what the display style does. Go and read up on the property http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp. style.display is not meant to hide and unhide a span tag. That is what the visible tag is for. If you don't want the empty space when it is not showing then you use absolute positioning